# having problems with sqlalchemy OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i was reading and testing the tutorial of sqlalchemy, all was going well until i tried to get values i previusly added to the db. when i do this, i get a error message:

```
OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: userss
```

if i use close function to close my session, i get this:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: userss
[SQL: SELECT userss.id AS userss_id, userss.name AS userss_name, userss.fullname AS userss_fullname, userss.nickname AS userss_nickname
```

this is my code

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
engine=create_engine('sqlite:///prueba.db')
Base = declarative_base()
Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)
#defining a extension of declarative base
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ ='userss'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname=Column(String)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                            self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
#makin a session
session = Session()
ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', nickname='edsnickname')
session.add(ed_user)
#when line below is uncommented, the error changes
#session.close()  
our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()
```

i get error when i apply the `first()` to the `session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed')`, but when i don't, i get a query.filter object. i read some similar problems but i have not typo errors in the definition of User class. how can i solve this?
thank you so much!

Comment: pd: when i use commit after add ed:user, i get the error:OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: userss

Comment: i named the table userss in the definition but the same thing happen when i name it users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the table was not created.

```
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

With the following change it works:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
engine=create_engine('sqlite:///prueba.db')
Base = declarative_base()
Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)
#defining a extension of declarative base
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ ='userss'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname=Column(String)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                            self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)




# initialize tables
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


#makin a session
session = Session()
ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', nickname='edsnickname')
session.add(ed_user)
#when line below is uncommented, the error changes
#session.close()
our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()

print(our_user)
```